# Angularjs ng-table - how to pass parameters into DreamFactory db api call

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make ng-table work by [example 6](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6) (ajax data loading) but instead of using mock backend I use actual DreamFactory backend connected to MongoDB. My relevant code looks like this now:

```
    MainApp.factory('Servant', function ($resource) {
        "use strict";
        console.log('loading');
        return $resource('https://dsp-mydspname.cloud.dreamfactory.com:443/rest/mongodb/tablename/:id/?app_name=appname&fields=*', {}, { update: { method: 'PUT' }, query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        } });
    });

    var MainCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout, $resource, Servant, ngTableParams) {
        "use strict";
        $scope.action="Add";
        var Api = Servant;

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,          // count per page

            }, {
                total: 0,           // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    // ajax request to api
                    Api.get(params.url(), function(data) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            // update table params
                            params.total(data.record.length);
                            // set new data
                            $defer.resolve(data.record);
                        }, 500);
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

The table is displying data but it displays all data on one page, I cant figure out how to pass "count" and "offset" parameters into my api call. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response.  I played a little with ng-table and found that I was spending a lot of time trying to make it work and couldn't get it to.  So..I thought it would be more helpful to show you how to build your own table with pagination so you can adapt it for any situation that may arise using DreamFactory.  Here's the code.  You should be able to copy and paste.  Just make sure to add your table fields to the table row for data.  The table headers will populate automatically.

Here is the controller and the service with comments:

```
.controller('TableCtrl', ['$scope', 'Servant', function($scope, Servant) {


        // function to get records for building the table
        var _getRecords = function(fieldsStr, limitInt, offsetInt, schemaBool) {

            Servant.get({fields: fieldsStr, limit: limitInt, offset: offsetInt, include_schema: schemaBool},

                function(data) {
                    $scope.table = data;
                }
            )
        };


        // Get the total records on load
        Servant.get({fields: 'id'}, function(data) {

            // Get the total number of records
            $scope.totalRecords = data.record.length;
        });


        // Options for rest call
        $scope.fields = '*';
        $scope.currentOffset = 0;
        $scope.limit = 4;

        // Used to do pagination
        // store total records
        $scope.totalRecords = 0;

        // store page objects
        $scope.pageObjs = [];

        // Get initial data
        _getRecords($scope.fields, $scope.limit, $scope.currentOffset, true);


        // Pagination
        $scope.next = function() {

            //check if we are on the last page
            if ($scope.currentOffset == $scope.pageObjs[$scope.pageObjs.length - 1].pageOffset) {
                return false;
            }

            // we are not
            // advance the page
            else {
                $scope.currentOffset = $scope.currentOffset + $scope.limit;
                _getRecords($scope.fields, $scope.limit, $scope.currentOffset, true);
            }
        };

        // change page directly
        $scope.changePage = function (offsetInt) {

            $scope.currentOffset = offsetInt;
            _getRecords($scope.fields, $scope.limit, $scope.currentOffset, true);
        };


        $scope.back = function() {

            // are we on the first page
            if ($scope.currentOffset == 0) {
                return false
            }

            // we are not
            // go previous page
            else {
                $scope.currentOffset = $scope.currentOffset - $scope.limit;
                _getRecords($scope.fields, $scope.limit, $scope.currentOffset, true);
            }
        };


        // watch for total records to be populated.  When we have this number
        // we can generate our page objects that will help build our pagination
        $scope.$watch('totalRecords', function(newValue, oldValue) {

            var numPages = Math.ceil(newValue / $scope.limit);

            for(var i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {

                $scope.pageObjs.push({pageNumber: i, pageOffset: i*$scope.limit})
            }

        });

    }])
    .service('Servant', ['$resource', function($resource) {

        // define and return our $resource
        // replace /rest/db/TheTable with your mongodb/tablename
        // you don't need the port either

        return $resource('http://localhost:8081/rest/db/TheTable',
            {
                // set params to bind too
                app_name: APP_NAME
                fields: '@fields',
                limit: '@limit',
                offset: '@offset'
            },
            {
                // set update method to 'PUT'
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }
        )
    }]);
```

Here is the template i used:

```
<table class="table">
    <!-- this will build the table headers dynamically -->
    <!-- they will populate in order of the table's schema -->
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="field in table.meta.schema.field">
            {{field.name}}
        </th>
    </tr>

    <!-- replace these fields with your field names -->
    <!-- for example: {{row.YOUR_FIELD_NAME}} -->
    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in table.record">
        <td>
            {{row.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row.first_name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row.last_name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- this will build dynamically as well-->
<ul class="pagination">
    <li data-ng-click="back()"><a>&laquo;</a></li>
    <li data-ng-click="changePage(page.pageOffset)" data-ng-repeat="page in pageObjs"><a>{{page.pageNumber + 1}}</a>
    </li>
    <li data-ng-click="next()"><a>&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I had a lot of problems with ng-table too so this way would be the best. I will try it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for that code, I learned a lot from it and it works fine now. Great!